# Approximation of projection of a function and computation of dual basis

Tags: hilbert-spaces, duality-theorems, change-of-basis, projection, schauder-basis

Let $H=L^2(0,1)$ and $M$ be a linear manifold generated by $n$ independent functions, $\{b_1, \cdots, b_n\}$. Define the orthogonal projection $P_M : H \rightarrow M$ on $H$ into $M$. Then, we have for any $g \in H$,
$$
P_M g = \sum_{i=1}^n \langle g, b_i^*\rangle b_i
$$
where $b_i^*$ is the dual basis for $M$ of $b_i$. Generally, the computation of $b_i^*$ is very difficult because it requires the calculation of all pairs $\langle b_i, b_j \rangle$ unless $b_i$ is very simple or an orthonormal basis.

This difficulty motivates me to come up with some approximation method. Consider an orthonormal basis for $H$, say $\{e_i\}$. Then, $\{b_i\}$'s are expressed by an infinite series in terms of $\{e_i\}$, and define the truncated version of the infinite series, $\{\widetilde b_i\}$ defined by
$$
\widetilde b_i = \sum_{k=1}^N \alpha_{ik}e_k.
$$
Assume that we are able to compute $\alpha_{ij}$. Then, we can easily compute $\langle \widetilde b_i, \widetilde b_j \rangle $, allowing us to compute the dual basis $\widetilde b_i^*$ of $\widetilde b_i$.
Consequently, our hope is that $\widetilde b_i^* \approx b_i^*$ as $N$ increases.

I think this approach is surely legitimate. So, I am highly sure that it is well studied and established about the error, convergence and so on. But I cannot find any proper keywords... Anybody knows this kind of approaches??

Comment: It's not my area, but this seems like too much of a "meta-technique" to have a name or general theory. Perhaps if you picked a specific problem you'd like to attack you'd have better luck?

Comment: Have a look at Krylov subspace methods.

Comment: @ Joshua P. Swanson Thank you for your interest. I've searched "meta-technique" but I feel that it is a very general concept. Could you specify the keyword in more detail? Thanks!

Comment: @user10354138 Many thanks for your suggestion. I will check it out!